# Deploy Elasticsearch for Apache Spark on Kubernetes

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-spark, kubernetes, elasticsearch-hadoop

I'm wondering if anyone has experience configuring a Kubernetes cluster using the [Elasticsearch for Hadoop library](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/reference.html). I'm running into issues with the node discovery timing out when trying to write from spark to elasticsearch. I have Elasticsearch up and running thanks to the [elasticsearch-cloud-kubernetes](https://github.com/fabric8io/elasticsearch-cloud-kubernetes) plugin for ES, which handles discovery, but I'm not sure how best to configure elasticsearch-hadoop to be aware of the nodes (pods) within the kubernetes cluster. I've tried setting `spark.es.nodes` to a es-client service, but that doesn't seem to work. I'm also aware that I could enable [`es.nodes.wan.only`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html), but as noted in the documentation, this would *severely* impact performance, which defeats the purpose of having them running on the same cluster. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I know this post is old, but did you by any chance find a solution in the end? I am facing the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that schooled on elasticsearch-hadoop but have you tried pointing your elasticsearch-hadoop to your elasticsearch service instead of specific nodes? Your master nodes will normally take care of everything in your ES cluster.